# PHP exibir registro duplicados

Tags: php, mysql

Recentemente comecei desenvolver em PHP+MySQL ,estou com dúvida sobre exibição da query,segue cenário.
Estou fazendo select com 3 tabelas `mdl_logstore_standard`, `mdl_course` e `mdl_user`, aonde na tabela `mdl_logstore_standard` contém `FK` da `mdl_course` (courseid) e na tabela `mdl_user` (userid),quando executo query no console do banco retorna todos registro (inclusive os duplicados), mas quando faço o debug no PHP retorna os registro sem duplicados.

Gostaria que retornasse todos registro inclusive os duplicados:

Query:

```
SELECT u.firstname AS 'USUARIO',
   u.department AS 'DEPARTAMENTO', 
   l.id AS 'ID_LOG', 
   eventname, action, FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated),
   l.courseid as 'COD_CURSO', 
   c.id AS 'ID CURSO mdl_course',
c.fullname AS 'DESCRICAO CURSO'   
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log l,
   mdl_course c,
   mdl_user u  
WHERE    
   l.courseid = c.id AND l.userid =  u.id 
ORDER BY l.timecreated DESC LIMIT 50
```

PHP.

```
 $sql ="SELECT u.firstname AS 'USUARIO',
        u.department AS 'DEPARTAMENTO', 
        l.id AS 'ID_LOG',   
        eventname, action, FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated),   
        l.courseid as 'COD_CURSO', c.id AS 'ID CURSO mdl_course',   
        c.fullname AS 'DESCRICAO CURSO'   
        FROM   mdl_logstore_standard_log l,mdl_course c , mdl_user u  
        WHERE l.courseid = c.id   AND  l.userid =  u.id 
        ORDER BY l.timecreated DESC LIMIT 50";
```

Execução da consulta:

```
$start_consulta = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

Exibição da consulta:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($start_consulta); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: O que há dentro do método `get_records_sql`?

Comment: Parâmetros conexão Banco de Dados ,estou desenvolvendo para ambiente AVA  Moodle,sistema integrado.